# Sorting a Pandas DataFrame by both column and row index at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, df, that I want to sort by both columns and rows at the same time.

```
data = {'c2': ['4.0', '2.0', '1.0', '3.0'],
       'c1': ['200', '100', '300', '400'],
       'c3': ['aa', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index = ['d', 'b', 'c', 'a']
df
```

I have no problem sorting by either of them, but I cannot figure out how to get them sorted at the same time. I would like the output to have the columns sorted by 'c1', 'c2', 'c3' and the rows to be 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'. Don't think it is very difficult but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: please post the df not an image, also what is the expected output after the sorting?

Comment: Please update your question following these guidelines and someone will be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I edited the post to include the code and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain `sort_index`:

```
df.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    c1   c2  c3
a  400  3.0  ee
b  100  2.0  cc
c  300  1.0  dd
d  200  4.0  aa
```